# MySQL: How can I make this subquery work while updating a value?

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, rollback

I'm trying to write a query that lists an Item ID, Title, old price, and new price. I can't do an update statement because then I don't think I could list the old price.

*INSTRUCTION:*

> USE A SUBQUERY to Increase price of all items by ‘No Rest for the Weary’ by 10%. Show prices before and after.  Rollback after.

There are three **main goals** to this assignment based on instruction:
1. Show old price. 
2. Show new price through calculation using a subquery. 
3. Use a rollback once finished.

Questions:
Is it possible to put an UPDATE inside of a SELECT statement like a subquery?
(Answer is apparently no.)

**Where I've run into issue:**

```
UPDATE items
SET unit_price = ROUND(unit_price + (unit_price * .10),2) as 'New Price'
WHERE item_id = 
    (SELECT item_id as 'Item ID',
              title as 'Title',
              unit_price as 'Old Price', --Except this won't work because the unit price is now the new price...
    FROM items
    WHERE title = 'No Rest for the Weary'
    );
```

This is what I have now, but the ROLLBACK bit has me stuck. Where would one put that in this situation? Or have I misunderstood the instructions entirely?

```
  SELECT item_id as 'Item ID', title as 'Title', unit_price as 'Price',
    ROUND(unit_price + (unit_price * .10),2) as 'New Price'
FROM items
WHERE item_id =
    (SELECT item_id 
    FROM items
    WHERE title = 'No Rest for the Weary'
    );
```

Comment: I'm not a MySQL wiz, but your nested query is returning 3 things instead of one, so your equality "item_id =" will always fail.  Try "where item_id = (select item_id from items where title = 'No Rest for the Weary').

Comment: Options OTOH: (1) trigger inserts in a history table (2) first do your selecting & calculating, only then update, possibly in a locking transaction to avoid race conditions (price changes during query run).

Comment: @TGray If I do that though, where would I change the price? In the original select statement?

Comment: Help me understand a bit more what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you actually trying to update the price while also displaying both the old and the new price?

Comment: Yes, sort of. I need to display the old price before changing it to the new price. I'm assuming this all needs to be done in one query

Comment: Can't be done in one query. We can easily calculate a new unit_price, as a percentage increase of the current unit_price, and return that in a resultset, along with the current unit_price. But it's not possible to do that *and* update a table in the same statement.  An `UPDATE` statement doesn't return a result, and a `SELECT` statement doesn't perform updates.

Comment: @spencer7593  Well, thanks for answering that part. I'm sorry this is very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to include an `UPDATE` statement within a `SELECT` statement. But it is possible to include a `SELECT` inside an `UPDATE`.

---

Why do you need an `UPDATE` statement?  Is the intent to *update* a column in a table with a new value, so the new value is persisted?

Or, is the intent to return a resultset?  An `UPDATE` statement doesn't return a resultset like a `SELECT` statement does.

The `UPDATE` statement in the question won't work, because there are three columns being returned by the subquery.  Used in the context

```
col IN (subquery)
```

The subquery should return only one column. It's invalid to return two or more columns.

You can write a SELECT statement that returns the result of an expression. In this example, a new unit price as a 10% increase over the current unit_price...

```
SELECT i.item_id                 AS `item_id`
     , i.title                   AS `title`
     , i.unit_price              AS `old_unit_price`
     , ROUND(i.unit_price*1.1,2) AS `new_unit_price`
  FROM items i
 WHERE i.title = 'No Rest for the Weary'
 ORDER BY i.item_id
```

If that's return the result you want, and you want to use that in an `UPDATE` to assign a new value to the `unit_price` column, assuming `item_id` is the PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY on the `items` table...

```
UPDATE ( SELECT r.*
           FROM ( -- select statement above goes here 
                  SELECT i.item_id                 AS `item_id`
                       , i.title                   AS `title`
                       , i.unit_price              AS `old_unit_price`
                       , ROUND(i.unit_price*1.1,2) AS `new_unit_price`
                    FROM items i
                   WHERE i.title = 'No Rest for the Weary'
                ) r
        ) s
   JOIN items t
     ON t.item_id = s.item_id
    SET t.unit_price = s.new_unit_price
```

Again, to emphasize the point, this assumes that `item_id` is the PRIMARY KEY (or a non-NULL UNIQUE KEY) on the `items` table.

Following the `UPDATE` statement, re-running the original SELECT query will return different results (assuming the original unit_price was sufficiently greater than zero.)

---

**FOLLOWUP**

1. Create query that shows old price

The first SELECT in the answer above shows the "old price" (assuming that the "old price" is stored in the `unit_price` column.)

2. Change the price to 10% more than the current price.

The first SELECT in the answer above shows adding 10% to the `unit_price` column, rounded to two digits after the decimal point, returned as another column `new_unit_price`.

3. Use a subquery

The first query doesn't use a subquery. But we could easily add one. (I'm not understanding why we need to add an unnecessary subquery.  Does it matter what that subquery returns, can we use a subquery in the SELECT list, or in the WHERE clause, does an inline view qualify as a subquery?)

This version adds two unnecessary correlated subqueries to the SELECT list, an unnecessary inline view, and an unnecessary subquery in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT i.item_id                 AS `item_id`
     , ( SELECT t.title
           FROM items t
          WHERE t.item_id = i.item_id
         ORDER BY t.title
         LIMIT 1
        )                        AS `title`
     , ( SELECT p.unit_price
           FROM items p
          WHERE p.item_id = i.item_id
         ORDER BY p.unit_price
         LIMIT 1
       )                         AS `old_unit_price`
     , ROUND(i.unit_price*1.1,2) AS `new_unit_price`
  FROM items i
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS i ) i
 WHERE i.title = (SELECT 'No Rest for the Weary')
 ORDER BY i.item_id
```

---

A simpler version of the `UPDATE` statement (to add 10% to unit_price) also doesn't require a subquery.

```
UPDATE items t
   SET t.unit_price = ROUND(t.unit_price*1.1,2)
 WHERE t.title = 'No Rest for the Weary'
```

Again, it's not possible for an `UPDATE` statement to return a resultset.

Comment: So I know it was probably delayed in reaching you, but would I be able to use a ROLLBACK in a select statement?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm probably misunderstanding something here. So, is a ROLLBACK a part of an UPDATE statement?

Comment: No. `ROLLBACK` is an entirely separate statement, And in order to issue a ROLLBACK statement, you'll need to execute a separate `START TRANSACTION` statement, then run the UPDATE, and then run the SELECT to get the modified price, and then issue a ROLLBACK  to revert the changes made in the transaction. And the table you are updating will need to be using a storage engine that supports rollback (for example InnoDB, rather than MyISAM.)

Comment: Reviewing everything, I think I see what you mean. Thanks for your help and your patience.